# Retrieve string from object using Object.keys

Tags: javascript, object

An object which contains 4 string, from this object i need the data one by one i have tried Object.keys(Object_name).[index] but data couldn't retrieve.

this is the object:

```
Object_name={
  0: "A",
  1: "R",
  2: "E",
  3: "A"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using `.index` makes no sense on an array

Comment: `Object.keys(Object_name)[index]` possibly?

Comment: What do you mean by " i need the data one by one"? Something like: `Object.keys(Object_name).forEach(k => { console.log(Object_name[k]); });`?

Comment: i gave like Object.keys(Object_name)[1] and i got undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys(Object_name)` will print `[0, 1, 2, 3]` so if you do `Object.keys(Object_name)[0]` you'll get 0, 1 for 1 etc ... `[0, 1, 2, 3][0] => 0` if you get `undefined` define your `object_name`

As far as I understand you want to loop on object name and get every Object value using Object keys

```
Object.keys(Object_name).forEach(key => { console.log(Object_name[key]); });
```

To read more about [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.entries:

```
Object_name={
  0: "A",
  1: "R",
  2: "E",
  3: "A"
} 
Object.entries(Object_name).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
});
```